# Default Nested Collection in Mongoose with Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an app with Node and MongoDB and I have a company model and an API key model that look like this in Mongoose:

```
  var APIKeysSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String }
  });

  var CompanySchema = new Schema({
      name            : {type : String, required: true, index: { unique: true }}
    , apiKeys           : [ APIKeysSchema ]
    , created_at      : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
  });
```

I'd like every company to have by default one API key generated when the company is created. Should I write custom middleware for this, or is there some way to do it within the schema itself. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a `default:` function for `apiKeys` that creates the default entry you're looking for?

Comment: I just ended up adding middleware

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just doing it as middleware on save in the model:

```
CompanySchema.pre('save', function(next){
    if(this.get('apiKeys').length < 1){
        //generate API key
        var objectId = new ObjectID();
        this.get('apiKeys').push({ key: objectId.toHexString() });
    }
    next();
  });
```

Comment: Won't that add another entry to `apiKeys` every time you save the document?

Comment: Yea...realized that afterwards. Changed it to add a check to see if one already exists...